# Deep destructuring with saving values

Tags: javascript, destructuring, object-destructuring

How to destruct and save nested values?

```js
const obj = {
    foo: {
        bar: 'Hi!'
    }
};

const { foo: { bar } } = obj;

console.log(bar); // Hi!
console.log(foo); // foo is not defined :(
```

How to keep foo value?

Comment: `const { foo: { bar }, foo } = obj;`

Answer (score 0):

Just take `foo` as target, too.

```js
const obj = {
    foo: {
        bar: 'Hi!'
    }
};

const { foo: { bar }, foo } = obj;

console.log(bar); // Hi!
console.log(foo); // foo
```

Comment: Thank you! But I hoped what have more DRY method)

Comment: otherwise you would get all outer properties as value, which is not implemented.